# Adding an index column for a table with one column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table named "Colors" in power BI with only one column

### Color

Red
Green
Blue
Cyan
Grey
Etc.

I need to add an index column with DAX that begins from 1 for the first row, 2 for the second row, 3 for the third row,....

I tried to use GENERATESERIES but it results in a table for each cell which is not what i want because i only need 1,2,3,... scalar values that correspond to each row

I also do not want to use power query

I would be grateful if you help

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that's weird. Why not use PowerQuery? That's the ideal way to do it. Please explain your rationale for removing options.

Comment: Because my boss has asked me to do it with DAX

Answer (score 0):

First calculate a measure

```
Measure = MAX('Table'[Color])
```

Then calculate Rankx measure

```
Index = RANKX(ALL('Table'), [Measure])
```

[image]